# How can I solve the error during installing of 'ydata-profiling'?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, profiling, modulenotfounderror, exploratory-data-analysis

Can anybody help me what to do?
My python version is Python 3.9.13.

**This is the code:**
!pip install ydata-profiling
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9224\756189906.py in 
1 #!pip install pandas-profiling
2 get_ipython().system('pip install ydata-profiling')
----> 3 from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ydata_profiling'

! How to solve the error and how can I use the functionalities of ydata-profiling?

Comment: I suggest that you use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting of your question.